# android fragment's view is not loaded on activity

Tags: android

Here is my MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var localFragment :Fragment
lateinit var outFragment : Fragment
lateinit var bottomNavigationView:BottomNavigationView
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    localFragment = LocalFragment()
    outFragment = OutFragment()

    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, localFragment)
    bottomNavigationViewInit()
}
    fun bottomNavigationViewInit(){
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNav) as BottomNavigationView
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item: MenuItem ->
            when(item.itemId){
                R.id.tab1 -> {
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, localFragment).commit()
                    return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
                R.id.tab2 -> {
                    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, outFragment).commit()
                    return@setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
                }
            }
            false

        }
    }
}
```

and here is my fragment xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".LocalFragment">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.95"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/fab_drawable"
        android:text="작성하기"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorGrey"
        android:id="@+id/goWritePost_button"
        ></Button>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

At first Mainactivity loaded, the button doesn't appear. but if I click the tab, then at last it appears. what is wrong??
At first Mainactivity loaded, the button doesn't appear. but if I click the tab, then at last it appears. what is wrong??

Comment: Didn't you forgot to `.commit()` for the fragment transaction in `onCreate()`?

Comment: Add ```.commit()``` to this line : ```supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, localFragment).commit()```